# Python - How to record an application window to a video?

Tags: python, video-capture

I have a python application, and I need to save this window action to a video file.

This application can be minimized, or the user can put another window in the front, but I need steel saving this window actions

Is it possible ?

ok:

I'm using Gnome,  pygtk, X11

I need save all live of my application to a video

Comment: Sorry. This application run on linux systems

Comment: It's better to edit your question and add that more detail.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to make an application record its own window, what user interface toolkit are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Periodically use [`Window.get_snapshot`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--get-snapshot) to get snapshots of the window. Then compose these images into a video. A simple though inefficient mechanism I can think of to do this is for each frame, convert your [`Pixmap`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixmap.html) into a [`Pixbuf`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixbuf.html) using [`Pixbuf.get_from_drawable`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixbuf.html#method-gdkpixbuf--get-from-drawable). Then use [`Pixbuf.save`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixbuf.html#method-gdkpixbuf--save) to save each frame to a PNG. When the application has finished, compose all of these PNGs into a video using [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: Yes, i'm doing it capturing 15 frames per second. But it consume alot of cpu

Comment: @BrunoPitteliGonçalves: That's bound to happen. I don't think there's any way you could make it take any less CPU without a lot more effort.